# Se puede hacer un Update de varios elementos de mi tabla a la vez?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla de clientes de una caja de un banco. Hay diferentes campos, como Identificador, Cod_Usuario, Nombre_Usuario, Correro_Usuario...
tengo que modificar un campo de cuatro clientes distintos pero que pertenecen a la misma tabla:

```
update miTabla
set Fec_Anulación = '26/03/2018 18:00'
where Cod_usuario in ('u251', 'u252', 'u253', 'u254')
```

pero no sé si la sentencia del where me da error. Me podéis echar un cable? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Debes agregar el mensaje de error que te sale, ya que asi como esta, la sentencia no parece incorrecta

Comment: cuál es el código exacto que estás usando?, qué tipo de datos tiene cada columna de tu tabla?

Comment: usuario1, usuario2, usuario3, son los códigos que les asignaste a cada uno o es solo un ejemplo?, si son sus códigos podrías ponerlos entre comillas ya que serían de tipo varchar.

Comment: sí, son ejemplos, los códigos de los usuarios ya los tengo entre comillas, pero no sé si el update me daría error por el where. porque no sé si se pueden poner 3 valores dentro del parentesis

Comment: Como ya te han dicho, sería mejor si colocas la query con datos de ejemplo, pero que sean fieles en cuanto a la forma a como lo estás intentando. Eso, además de la estructura de las tablas en juego.

Comment: por eso decía que pusieras tu código real....al ponerlo sin comillas en tu ejemplo confundes a los usuarios que pueden responder. Ayúdanos a ayudarte

Comment: No has probado tu código para ver si te arroja error o no?. Sí puedes usar 3 valores dentro de un `IN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que no te de error la modificación tendría que ser así

```
update miTabla
set Fec_Anulación = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-03-26 18:00',120)
where Cod_usuario in ('u251', 'u252', 'u253', 'u254')
```